# Como consigo cambiar letras en un inpuyt por asteriscos en python 3.1

Tags: python-3.x, contraseña

Tengo que hacer una tarea en la que debo conseguir hacer que la contraseña se ponga como asterico con cada tecla que pulse, cuando lo use, hay alguien que me pueda ayudar con esto? Lo unico es que esta en catalan

```
import getpass

Contraseña = "abc123"
intents = 1  
nom_de_usuari = input("Posa el teu nom d'usuari ")
print ('*', end='')
Contraseña_introduida = getpass.getpass("Posa la teva contraseña")    
while Contraseña_introduida != Contraseña:
  print("Contrasenya incorrecta")
  intents = intents + 1
  print ('*', end='')
  Contraseña_introduida = getpass.getpass("Posa la teva contraseña")
print("Inici de sessio exitos benvingut/a {} has fet {} intents per aconseguir la teva contraseña" .format(nom_de_usuari, intents))
igo aquí
```